# RNG (random number generators)

Tags: r, random

I'm new in random numbers generators field. I would like to use the Mersenne-Twister algorithm since  it has the longest period respect to other algorithms.

- Which R function implements this algorithm? I used 
  "?sample" but no information about which algorithm is used, is there.
- Another question is: which is the best seed to set in the random number generation?
- Finally: is R the best tool to generate random numbers?

Comment: The answer is in `?Random`, as linked to from `?sample`

Comment: A lot depends on what you want to do.  As @AustinHenley says, R does implement Mersenne-Twister, and uses it by default in *all* of its pseudo-random number operations (`runif`, `sample`, etc.). Is it the best tool? I don't know, but it's a perfectly reasonable tool (if you know you want MT, any competent implementation should do reasonably well ...) If you want true randomness or cryptographic-strength randomness, you may want to look at the results of `library("sos"); findFn("cryptographic random number generator")` or `findFn("random.org")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The default algorithm used by R is Mersenne-Twister.
- There is no best seed. It depends on your application. Do you want it to be the same set of numbers every time you run your code? Use the same seed(s). If not, perhaps using the current time will suit your needs.
- The best tool to generate random numbers is something that does **not** use a deterministic PRNG (such as Mersenne-Twister). Instead look into something such as [random.org](http://random.org). I think it will really benefit you to read up on [True randomness vs. Pseudo randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers).